# Start a file download from chrome devtool extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I basically want to create a chrome extension that automatically download files under a certain criteria whenever I browser them.

By following the samples and documentations, I have a "devtool" type extension that successfully alert me whenever I encounter such a file. I am trying to add the download part without any success. Is it possible that file download from such script are automatically denied? I made sure to add "downloads" to the permission in the manifest.

Here is basically everything :

```
chrome.devtools.network.onRequestFinished.addListener(
  ChromeFirePHP.handleFirePhpHeaders.bind(ChromeFirePHP);
);

ChromeFirePHP.handleFirePhpHeaders = function(har_entry) {
 var parser = document.createElement('a'),
    params = null,
    channel = null,
    message = null,
    subscribe_key = null,
    channels = [],
    i = 0;

  parser.href = har_entry.request.url;
  if(parser.pathname.indexOf('.jpg') != -1) {
        alert('Downloading : ' + har_entry.request.url); //alerts a complete url

        chrome.downloads.download({url: har_entry.request.url}); //nothing happens
        chrome.downloads.download({url: har_entry.request.url,saveAs: true},function(id){alert(id);}); //2nd try, nothing happens

    }
};
```

I've tried different file types and URL, hard-coding some download urls, nothing does it.

Relevant manifest.json part :

```
"permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "notifications",
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*",
    "<all_urls>",
    "downloads",
    "downloads.open"
  ],
```

Comment: Could you check the urls format? Try to use `"http://*/*"` and `"https://*/*"` or `"<all_urls>"` instead in `"permissions"` field.

Comment: Good thinking, I see how it would make sense. Unfortunately, I've tried this and it makes no difference.

Comment: Well is there any error message you're running with?